# How to set custom HTTP code in MarkLogic REST function

Tags: javascript, rest, http, postman, marklogic

In MarkLogic 9, I'm using a custom SJS service with POST method where I do some basic search & validation giving a custom result for errors (Not using fn.error because of requirements).

The error that I return in POSTMAN is a simple JSON like this:

```
{
"code":400,
"message":"Bad request",
"reason":"string"
}
```

The HTTP code-message header above the response in POSTMAN shows "200 OK" even after using `xdmp.setResponseCode(400, "Bad request");`

How to set the HTTP code to a manual number/message while following the standard protocols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether the custom SJS service is

- a Data Service endpoint

  Set the errorDetail property in the *.api declaration and throw
  the error mapped to the HTTP status code (see
  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/DataServices#id_74238).
- a REST API resource service extension

  For a 2xx status, set the `outputStatus` property on
  the `context` parameter object (see
  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_26045).

  For a 4xx status, throw a `RESTAPI-SRVEXERR` error (see
  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_20992).
- an HTTP endpoint module

  Call the `xdmp.setResponseCode()` function (see https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.setResponseCode)

Hoping that helps,